# Add checkbox column without binding in Kendo Grid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I try to add a checkbox column in my kendo grid. I use the code in this link :

http://www.telerik.com/support/code-library/select-grid-rows-using-checkboxes-and-preserve-it-between-the-pages

But it doesn't work with a razor page.
Here's my code :

cshtml :

```
      @(Html.Kendo().Grid<IQuestArchive>().Name("archivesGrid")
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource.Ajax().Read(read => read.Action("Archives_Read", "Home").Type(HttpVerbs.Get))
        .Sort(sort => sort.Add("Name").Ascending())).Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Template(@<text></text>).ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' class='checkbox'/>").Title("<input type='checkbox'/>").Width(10);
                columns.Bound(request => request.ReadableName).Title("Name");
            }).Sortable().Selectable(builder => builder.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Multiple).Type(GridSelectionType.Row)))
```

script:

```
   //bind click event to the checkbox
   $("#archivesGrid").table.on("click", ".checkbox" , selectRow);

   //on click of the checkbox:
    function selectRow() {
        var checked = this.checked,
            row = $(this).closest("tr"),
            grid = $("#archivesGrid").data("kendoGrid"),
            dataItem = grid.dataItem(row);

        checkedIds[dataItem.id] = checked;
        if (checked) {
            //-select the row
            row.addClass("k-state-selected");
        } else {
            //-remove selection
            row.removeClass("k-state-selected");
        }
    }
```

I don't understand what's going wrong and if I compare with the code in link before it's exactly the same logic...:s

Comment: You need a reference of your kendo grid widget. To do this use this code: $("#archivesGrid").data("kendoGrid")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take a closer look; I can tell you one difference; you're doing

```
$("#archivesGrid").table.on("click", ".checkbox" , selectRow);
```

whereas the demo does

```
var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
//...
}).data("kendoGrid");

//bind click event to the checkbox
grid.table.on("click", ".checkbox" , selectRow);
```

It's important to understand what the code is doing so you can debug it. JQuery elements don't have a table property. It's a property of the Kendo UI grid widget.